# in sas how do i fix this error ERROR: The macro VV contains at least one %GOTO statement, but no valid labels were defined?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I get an error when using %goto in a macro: The error is;
ERROR: The macro vv contains at least one %GOTO statement, but no valid labels were defined.

The code I run is as below.

How do I get fix this error please.

```
%macro vv(dsetin=);
   %if %sysfunc(exist(&dsetin)) %then %goto exit;

   data t;
    set &dsetin;
   run;

   %exit;
%mend vv;

%vv(dsetin=sashelp.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the semi-colon after the label EXIT to a a colon.  With a semi-colon there it looks like a call to a macro named EXIT instead of the definition of a label named EXIT.

You also might want to reverse the logic of the %IF statement so that it makes more sense.

```
%macro vv(dsetin=);
%if not %sysfunc(exist(&dsetin)) %then %goto exit;

data t;
  set &dsetin;
run;

%exit:
%mend vv;

%vv(dsetin=sashelp.class);
```

Comment: Fantastic... Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `%goto` here; there is a SAS statement whose job it is to do what you're asking.  [`%RETURN`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/p0qyygqt5a69xnn1rhfju3kjs8al.htm) will exit the macro for you...

Using Tom's suggested modification:

```
%macro vv(dsetin=);
%if not %sysfunc(exist(&dsetin)) %then %return;

data t;
  set &dsetin;
run;

%mend vv;

%vv(dsetin=sashelp.class);
```